# Notice: Undefined index

Tags: php, mysql

I have a checkbox which can make a post password protected-

```
<p><strong><label for="password">Password protect?</label></strong> <input type="checkbox" name="password" id="password" value="1" /></p>
```

My Php tries to post-

```
 $password = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['password']));
```

I get the undefined index error.

Now, if I try to check first if the password was set, I get the same error executing-

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO blog (timestamp,title,entry,password) VALUES ('$timestamp','$title','$entry','$password')";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or print("Can't insert into table blog.<br />" . $sql . "<br />" . mysql_error());
```

How do I fix it? Do I have to do it for every field like title text box and all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you stripping tags and escaping a boolean value? You could just do it like this:

```
$password = (isset($_POST['password']) && $_POST['password'] == 1) ? 1 : 0;
```

or:

```
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? (bool) $_POST['password'] : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably get an undefined *variable* warning the second time. You can e.g.assure that $password is set regardless of whether _POST[xyz] is set or not.

```
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '0';
```

see http://docs.php.net/ternary

Answer (score 1):

You receive the *undefined index* because your accessing a non-existing array indices.

You should make sure the value is set before setting it:

```
if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
   $password = $_POST['password'];
}
```

Comment: I feel old school going the `if` statement route opposed to the conditional operator. :(

Answer (score 0):

A checkbox value is only returned if the checkbox is selected. Therefore, if the password checkbox is not selected, the key `password` does not exist in the `$_POST` array.

You could do:

```
$password = array_key_exists('password', $_POST) ? '1' : '0';
```